# WebApi Controller action parameter base class for common features

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Where WebApi Controller actions share identical features, E.g. pagination and partial response, is it possible to create a base class to model these parameters?

For example, this URI:

http://letsdoitclean.com/api/v1/athletes?clean=true&fields=name,age&offset=0&limit=25

might map to:

```
class AthletesController
{
    IHttp Get(bool clean, string[] fields, int offset, int limit)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, `fields`, `offset` and `limit` are concepts that will be frequently used. So I want something like:

```
abstract class ActionParameter
{
    public string[] fields;
    public int offset;
    public int limit;
}

class AthletesGetParameter : ActionParameter
{
    public bool clean;
}

class AthletesController
{
    IHttp Get(AthletesGetParameter param)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can do this.  ASP.NET will handle the parameter binding if you, in this example, specify the [`FromUriAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for the complex object:

```
public class AthletesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get([FromUri] AthletesGetParameter athletesGetParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The only thing I would argue *against* from your question, is the name of the `abstract class`.  It doesn't really describe the base class all that well and what it's intended for.  Maybe something like `abstract class PaginationParameter` or something similar.  To call it `ActionParameter` could confuse you in the future (or other programmers) that all action parameters should derive this class, and I don't think that's right.

Maybe minutia on the naming of the base class, but to answer your direct question... ***yes you can do this***.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The naming was given no thought. Contrived to provide an example. I agree with your feedback.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Ah, I figured as much. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be achieved by adding it globally to your WebApiConfig so that you don't have to mark it up in every single controller action:

```cs
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor =>
            typeof(ActionParameter).IsAssignableFrom(descriptor.ParameterType)
                ? new FromUriAttribute().GetBinding(descriptor)
                : null);
```